# How can I detect if user disable GPS (Android - Play Services)

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

I use gms.location.LocationListener (Google Play Services) to get the user's location. It works fine but I want to detect whenever the user disables or enables his/her GPS.
As in this picture.

[image]

When I turn ON/OFF location no methods are called. 
When I switch apps and return to my app this methods are called:

- onStart
- onResume
- onConnected

But I need the event to be called whenever the user turns ON/OFF location those events I listed don't get called.

Note: With Android API I am able to get those events with onProviderEnabled and onProviderDisabled my problem there is that those events don't get called anymore after I use GoogleApiClient. See picture 2 and 3.
[image: Use location Window]
[image: Use location window]
After that onProviderEnabled and onProviderDisabled don't get called well that's another problem I'd like to solve both.

- **Android Studio 1.5.1**
- **Testing in Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900W8 Android 5.0, API 21)**

My Code:

```
package facilito.codigo.app.dflores.com.myapplicationcf;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;//android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import Beans.Usuario;
import Beans.Utiles;

public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
                                                      GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                                                      GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                                                      LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double lat = 0.0;
    private double lon = 0.0;
    PolygonOptions comunidad = new PolygonOptions();
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                        // initialize location requests here.
                        Log.d("BUHOO", "case success :::::::::::>>>>>>>>>>>");
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                        // by showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            Log.d("BUHOO", "case RESOLUTION_REQUIRED :::::::::::>>>>>>>>>>>");
                            status.startResolutionForResult(Mapa.this, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.d("BUHOO", "case SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE :::::::::::>>>>>>>>>>>");
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                        // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("BUHOO_APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(pref.getInt("ID_USUARIO", 0), pref.getString("NOMBRE_USUARIO", null));
        int idComu = pref.getInt("ID_COMUNIDAD", 0);
        String server = getResources().getString(R.string.ip_server);
        String servicio = "http://"+server+"/buhoo/intranet/mi_comunidad/getComunidadByPersona_Service?id_persona="+usuario.getIdUsuario()+"&id_comunidad="+idComu;
        Log.d("BUHOO", "servicioservicioservicio:::::: "+servicio);
        new llamarServicio().execute(servicio);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onConnected ::::");
        try {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        } catch(SecurityException e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            Log.d("BUHOO", " ERROR onLocationChanged "+errors.toString());
        }
        //if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        //}
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onConnectionSuspended ::::");
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onStart ::::");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onStop ::::");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onPause ::::");
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onResume ::::");
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() /*&& !mRequestingLocationUpdates*/) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        try {
            Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: startLocationUpdates ::::");
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } catch(SecurityException e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            Log.d("BUHOO", " ERROR onLocationChanged "+errors.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onConnectionFailed ::::");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", "onLocationChanged:::::: "+location.getLatitude()+"   longitud: "+location.getLongitude());
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        onMapReady(mMap);
    }


/*
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onProviderEnabled ::::");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("BUHOO", ":::: onProviderDisabled ::::");
    }*/

    private class llamarServicio extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Utiles utiles = new Utiles();
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return utiles.readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Log.d("BUHOO", "result:::::: "+result);
                JSONObject mainResponseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                try {
                    String error = mainResponseObject.getString("error");
                    if("0".equals(error)) {
                        JSONObject polyObj = new JSONObject(mainResponseObject.getString("poligono"));
                        String puntos = polyObj.getString("puntos");
                        List<String> puntosList = Arrays.asList(puntos.split(","));
                        for(Iterator it = puntosList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                            String str = (String) it.next();
                            String[] latlon = str.split(" ");
                            double lati  = Double.parseDouble(latlon[0].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                            double longi = Double.parseDouble(latlon[1].replaceAll("\"", ""));

                            comunidad.add(new LatLng(lati, longi));
                            //Log.d("BUHOO", "lati:::::: "+lati+"  ... "+longi);
                        }
                        Log.d("BUHOO"," onPostExecute cantidad latlongs: "+comunidad.getPoints().size());
                        onMapReady(mMap);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("CREATION", " ---- error inesperdo: " );
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                    Log.d("CREATION", "tratando el JSON: "+errors.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                Log.d("CREATION", "errorrrr onPostExecute: "+errors.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        if(lat != 0.0 && lon != 0.0) {
            LatLng myPos = new LatLng(lat, lon);
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPos).title("MI POSICION ACTUAL"));
            float zoomLevel = 17; //This goes up to 21
            //Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(comunidad);
            Log.d("BUHOO"," PINTANDO MAPA cantidad latlongs: "+comunidad.getPoints().size());
            if(comunidad.getPoints().size() > 0) {
                mMap.addPolygon(comunidad/*.fillColor(Color.BLUE)*/);
            }
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPos, zoomLevel));
        } else {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            Log.d("BUHOO", "PINTO SYDNEY");
        }
    }

public static class GPSCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            Log.d("BUHOO", " :D IS ON!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        } else {
            Log.d("BUHOO", " :( GPS TURNED OFF !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: For answer in Kotlin, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255136/12478830

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achive this by Setting up a **Broadcast Receiver** that gets fired whenever the GPS of your device turns on/off

**Steps:**

**1. First of all create a class GPS which extend BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GPSCheck extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {





            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please switch on the GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



    }


}
```

**2. And then mention this class in your AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackagename.example.GPSCheck" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**3. Do not forget to add this permission also**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: a put a Log.d method in the if and else part and it's printing twice, do you know why?

Comment: need to check it .. will let you know soon !

Comment: no such issue is coming up with my implementation .. works fine at my side !

Comment: I put public static class GPSCheck extends BroadcastReceiver{//your code} inside my class (embeded class) because I wanted to use some variables from my Activity class such as rerender my map. Is that the reason?

Comment: yes this might be a reason ..! as the same issue came to me once while using a Broadcast Receiver as a inner class.. can you show me your code?

Comment: I added my code, is the script you suggested but is inside my Activity class as an inner class

Answer (score 2):

I am using this class to listen in the changes with the GPS.

```
public class GpsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public interface LocationCallBack {
        void turnedOn();
        void turnedOff();
    }

    private final LocationCallBack locationCallBack;

    public GpsReceiver(LocationCallBack iLocationCallBack){
        this.locationCallBack = iLocationCallBack;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            locationCallBack.turnedOn();
        else
            locationCallBack.turnedOff();
    }
}
```

And register it on an onCreate of my activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver(new GpsReceiver(new GpsReceiver.LocationCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void turnedOn() {
                Log.e("GpsReceiver","is turned on");
            }
            @Override
            public void turnedOff() {
                Log.e("GpsReceiver","is turned off");
            }
        }), new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
}
```