# How to unregister a broadcast receiver properly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i followed this answer to register a receiver and it works perfect.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47216794/6486268)
now i wonder how to unregister it in the ondestroy?

Comment: can you show me the code how you are registering it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unregistering the broadcast receiver is simple, you call `unregisterReceiver` method and pass the broadcast receiver to it.

Based on the answer you've shared

1) Change the registering of broadcast receiver in the `onCreate` method to

```
registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

2) Declare a global variable

```
final BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new GpsReceiver(new LocationCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationTriggered() {
            //Location state changed
        }
    });
```

3) In the `onDestroy`, Unregister the broadcast receiver

```
unregisterReceiver(gpsReceiver);
```