# Get Device Location after a while

Tags: android, android-location

I'm wondering what's the best practice to update some data in the app with location related stuff when the user doesn't start the app with the location turned on and it doesn't need to prompt for it. Basically I want to update a list of stores in my local database with the distance relative to my location. I can't block the app to wait for the users location, I just want to detect when the user turns on the location services in order to update the entries.
At the moment I create custom LocationListeners and after I detect the location I turn them off, but I don't think that's the best practice. I uses too much battery keeping the listeners update interval and distance at a minimal value, and some users never turn on their location.

Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: have you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778807/how-to-detect-when-user-turn-on-off-gps-state the gps-status listener should work

Comment: no, looks promising, cheers