# In Oreo (8.0.0+) (API 26+), How to get a location services update when the app is in the background or kill

Tags: android, background, geolocation, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

In Android O (8.0.0+) (API 26+), How to get a location services update when the app is in the background or kill. In "Strava" Android App (Available on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava&hl=en)), location services run properly when the app is in the background or kill. I need to build same functionality in my app.
Whenever I start service using

```
startService(new Intent(this, GpsServices.class));
```

Then the onDestroy method is called after 10 sec when an app is an idle mode (the app is in the background or kill). Below is my code.

```
public class GpsServices extends Service implements LocationListener, Listener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
        }
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                500,
                0,
                this);
        }    
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("location = [" + location + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Services is stopped */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            mLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(this);
            stopForeground(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should read how to handle location in the background https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html

Comment: If you can provide a solution it would be helpful. I have already read the link you provided.But GeofencingApi and FusedLocationProviderApi interfaces are deprecated.

Comment: Please read the link, using those things have nothing to do with the actual issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try one of below two options or a combination of both, which have solved my problems when I have faced them.

### Option 1

For location update to continue running in the background, you must use [`LocationServices` API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices) with [`FusedLocationProviderClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) in docs or [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API) in CODEPATH.

### Option 2

If you would have read the Android Oreo 8.0 Documentation properly somewhere in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground), you would have landed on this solution.

> **Step 1:** Make sure you start a service as a foreground service as given in below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            mainActivity.startService(new Intent(getContext(), GpsServices.class));
            mainActivity.startService(new Intent(getContext(), BluetoothService.class));
            mainActivity.startService(new Intent(getContext(), BackgroundApiService.class));
        }
        else {
            mainActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(getContext(), GpsServices.class));
            mainActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(getContext(), BluetoothService.class));
            mainActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(getContext(), BackgroundApiService.class));
        }
```

> **Step 2:** Use notification to show that your service is running. Add below line of code in `onCreate` method of service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
    ...
}
```

> **Step 3:** Remove the `notification` when the service is stopped or destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          stopForeground(true); //true will remove notification
    }
    ...
}
```

One problem with **Option 2** is that it will keep showing the `notification` until your `GpsService` is running on all devices running on **Android Oreo 8.0**.

I'm sure that both these options will work even when the app is in the background or in kill state.

I hope this solution might solve your problem.

Comment: can we detect GPS ON/OFF before we start our foreground service?

Comment: yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778807/how-to-detect-when-user-turn-on-off-gps-state

Comment: This (GPS) solution doesn't work anymore in 8.0 for me

Comment: @moDev Have you found any solution to detect GPS ON/OFF in android (Oreo)8.0. Because the broadcast receiver no more use to detect GPS ON/OFF. If you found any solution please post the answer.

Comment: @Suresh There is no way to detect GPS On/Off in 8.0

Comment: For Option 1, don't you require a service for it to run in the background? Is this applicable for API 26 onwards?

Comment: For Option 2, once you close the app or navigate to other app, the service will killed automatically by android system.

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this problem appears to be a notification generator.  The following link describes a working solution better than I can summarize:

https://hackernoon.com/android-location-tracking-with-a-service-80940218f561